# PHP array problem

Tags: php, arrays

Every time I try to display the category I get the name Array instead of the `category` name. I was wondering how can I display the `category` names from my code below?

```
$list = array();
$cat = array();
$query = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT id, parent_id, category FROM categories ORDER BY parent_id, category LIKE category ASC");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $list[$row['id']] = array_merge($row, array('children' => array()));
}
mysqli_free_result($query);

foreach($list as $nodeId => &$node) {
    if(!$node['parent_id'] || !array_key_exists($node['parent_id'], $list)){
        $cat[] = &$node;
    } else {
        $list[$node['parent_id']]['children'][] = &$node;
    }
}
unset($node);
unset($list);
```

Var dump output example.

```
array
  0 => &
    array
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'parent_id' => string '0' (length=1)
      'category' => string 'Cat-1' (length=5)
      'children' => 
        array
          0 => &
            array
              ...
          1 => &
            array
              ...
          2 => &
            array
              ...
```

Comment: I dont see, where you are trying to display anything. Additional: Are you sure you want to unset `$list` right after you created it? Oo

Comment: do var_dump on the "problematic" variable and see the answer.

Comment: I did a var dump but still couldn't get it to work:(

Comment: @bazmegakapa I didn't post my display output because it didn't work

Comment: There really is no need to emphasize your ambiguous question title with additional exclamation marks...

Comment: @pNUT If you don't provide your "not working" display code, how would you expect us to fix it?

Comment: Why is everyone here is so up tight and rude?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you echo a variable, and the browser display's "Array", you need to go another level deeper to access the array elements.  You may have tried this already, but `var_dump()` your category array to view the structure of your array and verify it is what you expected it to be.  YOu will be able to analyze your apparent multi-dimensional array to judge how many loops you need to get to the category names.

Update:

to go a level deeper,  you need nested loops.  for example:

```
foreach($first_level as $first){
    foreach($first as $second_level){
        echo $second_level;
    }
}
```

Comment: how would I go a level deeper?

Answer (score 1):

This might or might not be your problem:

```
    $cat[] = &$node;
```

If you just want the category names, then you'd likely need to use:

```
    $cat[] = $node["category"];
```

When you otherwise print the list out, the subarrays will be converted into `"Array"` in string context.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get that `LIKE category ASC` at the end of your query what is it supposed to do?
otherwise Itay Moav is right `var_dump` it :) there are loads of really cool function to display `var_dump` correctly on the [php manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php).